# Is it possible to override a page with another include?

Tags: php, mysql

**THE PROBLEM**

The problem I've having is I can't override the current page with `include`.

```
if ($LS::getUser('clan') || isset($_GET['clan']) && !isset($_GET['search'])) {
    include("res/templates/clan-overview.php");
} else {
    include("res/templates/clan-search.php");
}
```

I don't get why I can't change the page with `clan-search.php` because I said that if `$_GET['search']` is NOT set execute the else statement. But for some weird reason I'm still getting `true` even though I said that if the user has a `CLAN || $_GET['clan']` AND `$_GET['search']`.

**What I've Tried**

That code I put at the top is actually the modified version of my original code which I thought would fix the problem. If you are interested in looking at the original code which I don't think will help you here it is:

```
if ($LS::getUser('clan') || isset($_GET['clan'])) {
    include("res/templates/clan-overview.php");
} else if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
    include("res/templates/clan-search.php");
}
```

Comment: I am a php fool. But is it a case of improper ( ) wrapping (lack thereof) cuz u have `and and or`

Comment: I'm assuming that you're expecting the `else` to run if the search GET variable is available whether the has, or has requested a clan? If so, as @DrewPierce says, you need `()` around the `||` condition. See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) for more info about operator precedence and associativity.

Comment: @JonStirling Yes Indeed! Oh okay I'll try that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Drew pierce  gave you first response as you need to wrap the OR parts as a group. try this:

```
if (($LS::getUser('clan') || isset($_GET['clan'])) && !isset($_GET['search'])) {
```